# Input mask em modal dinâmica

Tags: php, javascript, input-mask

Estou tendo "quase o mesmo" problemas. Eu gero listagem com modal dinâmica, e o input mask so é aplicado no primeiro laço do WHILE, nos demais não aplica. alguém consegue me ajudar?

Esse é o form que fica dentro da modal:

```
<form method="POST" action="anuidade.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="3">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_anuidade['id']; ?>">
  <fieldset class="border p-2" style="background-color: #F1F1F1;">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="aluno">Nome * </label>
        <input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" class="form-control" id="aluno" name="aluno" value="<?php echo $row_anuidade['aluno']; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf" value="<?php echo $row_anuidade['cpf']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="instrutor">Instrutor</label>
        <input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" class="form-control" id="instrutor" name="instrutor" value="<?php echo $row_anuidade['instrutor']; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="valor">Valor *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor" name="valor" value="<?php echo $row_anuidade['valor']; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="ano">Ano *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ano" name="ano" value="<?php echo $row_anuidade['ano']; ?>" maxlength="4" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="pago" name="pago" value="0">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="pago">Cancela o pagamento?</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>


  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Salvar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

E este é o Script que estou usando:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#cep').mask('00000-000');
   $('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
   $('#valor').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
   $('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-00009');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: É porque vc está repetindo id's. Só vai pegar no primeiro. Utilize class em vez de id.

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo, coisa besta e passa batido, vlw

Comment: Acontece amigo rs... a gente vai aprendendo junto. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repetir id na mesma página é errado. Um id deve ser único, é como uma identificação de um elemento, assim como um CPF onde cada cidadão tem o seu único.

Se você tem dois elementos com o mesmo id:

```
<input id="cpf">
<input id="cpf">
```

Ao tentar achar o elemento pelo id usando `$('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});` qual ele deverá achar? Todos? Não! Ele irá buscar apenas o primeiro, ignorando os outros.

Em vez de id, utilize `class` quando há mais de um elemento que irão receber a mesma coisa:

```
<input class="form-control cpf">
<input class="form-control cpf">
```

E aplique o plugin a todos os elementos que possuem a mesma classe:

```
$('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
```